# Im having difficulty displaying videos and images at the same time

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Here is my code, right now i have 2 filters 1 for displaying just images and the other for displaying just videos. The thing that i am having difficulty with is displaying images and videos in the same row. Because whenever i do so it will show the video/image and then a blank video/image depending on which of the two fields is emtpy in my db. Does anyone know how i can display videos and images as the default?

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    
    session_start();
    
    ?>
 

<body class="body">
    

          
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="submit" name="switch_video" value="switch to videos" id="switch_video">
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" name="switch_image" value="switch to images" id="switch_image">
        </form> 
        </span>
          </div> 
</body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['switch_video'])) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM meme_vote WHERE image = '' ORDER BY vote DESC LIMIT 500";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
} if(isset($_POST['switch_image'])) {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM meme_vote WHERE video_location = '' ORDER BY vote DESC LIMIT 500";
$res_image = mysqli_query($conn, $query2); }



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meme Voting System</title>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ $location = $row['video_location'];?>  

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="post">
                    <h4 class="post-title"><?php echo $row['title']?></h4>
                    <div class="postdesign">
                         <a  href="big_meme.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>">
                        <video src="<?php echo $row['video_location'] ?>" width="100%" height="240" controls></video>
                        </a>           <?php /*<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?= base64_encode($row['image']) ?>" height="280" width="240px" class="img-thumnail" />*/ ?>
                         <span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up " onclick="like_update('<?php echo $row['id']?>')">Like 
                        (<span class="like_loop_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['vote']?></span>) 
                        </span> </a>
                    <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Uploaded by: '; echo $row['username'] ?></p>
                        <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Category: '; echo $row['category']?></p>
                         </span>
    
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>    
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_image)){?>  

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="post">
                    <h4 class="post-title"><?php echo $row['title']?></h4>
                    <div class="postdesign">
                         <a  href="big_meme_image.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>">
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?= base64_encode($row['image']) ?>" height="280" width="240px" class="img-thumnail" />
                        </a>             <?php /*<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?= base64_encode($row['image']) ?>" height="280" width="240px" class="img-thumnail" />*/ ?>
                         <span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up " onclick="like_update('<?php echo $row['id']?>')">Like 
                        (<span class="like_loop_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['vote']?></span>) 
                        </span> </a>
                    <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Uploaded by: '; echo $row['username'] ?></p>
                        <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Category: '; echo $row['category']?></p>
                         </span>
    
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>    
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ $location = $row['video_location'];?>  

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="post">
                    <h4 class="post-title"><?php echo $row['title']?></h4>
                    <div class="postdesign">
                         <a  href="big_meme.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>">
                        <video src="<?php echo $row['video_location'] ?>" width="100%" height="240" controls></video>
                        </a>           <?php /*<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?= base64_encode($row['image']) ?>" height="280" width="240px" class="img-thumnail" />*/ ?>
                         <span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up " onclick="like_update('<?php echo $row['id']?>')">Like 
                        (<span class="like_loop_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['vote']?></span>) 
                        </span> </a>
                    <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Uploaded by: '; echo $row['username'] ?></p>
                        <p class="post_info"><?php echo 'Category: '; echo $row['category']?></p>
                         </span>
    
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>    
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .post_info {
     position: relative; left: 140px; bottom: 40px; 
}
    .post {
        position: relative; top: 100px;
    }
 
   
    </style>
<script>
     function like_update(id){
        var cur_count = jQuery('.like_loop_'+id).html();
        cur_count++
        jQuery('.like_loop_'+id).html(cur_count);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'update_count.php',
            type:'post',
            data:'type=like&id='+id,
            success:function(result){
            }
        })
}
</script>
    <script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is way too much code here for us to sift through. Please help us by removing all unnecessary code. Limit it to the absolute minimum we need to understand your problem.

Comment: I have removed all of the unnecessary code

Comment: OK, thanks. And what does a single row of _meme_vote_ look like?

Comment: eg. id:1 title:test video_location: videos/video0_6.mp4
vote: 4 video_name: video0_6.mp4 user_id: 2 username: Brad fake_vote: 4 category:tv

Comment: image: nothing.

Comment: or if it is an image post it would be eg. id:1 title:test video_location: nothing vote: 4 video_name: nothing user_id: 2 username: Brad fake_vote: 4 category:tv – Luca 22 secs ago   Edit   
image: [BLOB - 404.5 KiB]

Comment: I would create 2 tables both referencing the user id, one for image and one for video. This way you can return a result from both tables or either one.